# Is there a way to respond from an API endpoint with both a .PDF file and json data?

Tags: python, backend, fastapi

Im working with a FastAPI backend and a Reactjs UI, I have a single **/summarize** endpoint that receives a .PDF file along with some json data:

```py
@app.post("/summarize")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...), parameters: str = Form(...)):
```

Is is possible to respond with a newly generated .PDF file and json data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - requests are expected to return a single response, which could be a file (PDF), text, json, etc., but not multiple.

If I were building such an endpoint, I would add a field to my json response called "pdf_url", giving the React UI a new url to make a request to for the PDF file. The UI can then make a followup request to retrieve the PDF file. You will, however, need to set up the second route in FastAPI to serve the file.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to combining a file with JSON data in a single response it's a bit tricky because they're fundamentally different data types.

A common approach would be to send back a multi-part response typically in the form of a multi-part archive like a zip file that contains the generated PDF and a separate JSON file with the data. The client can then extract the archive to access both the PDF and JSON.

Here's a simple way to achieve this using the FastApi:

Install necessary libraries:

```
pip install fastapi[all] aiofiles python-multipart
```

Implement the /summarize endpoint:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, Form, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import shutil
import zipfile
import io
import json

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/summarize")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...), parameters: str = Form(...)):
    # Process your PDF and JSON data (this is just a placeholder step)
    processed_pdf_content = await file.read()  # For example purposes, we'll just use the uploaded file content
    json_data = json.dumps({"result": "Success", "parameters": parameters})

    # Create a zip archive in memory
    memory_file = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(memory_file, 'w') as zf:
        zf.writestr("result.pdf", processed_pdf_content)
        zf.writestr("data.json", json_data)

    memory_file.seek(0)

    return StreamingResponse(memory_file, media_type="application/zip", headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=summary.zip"})
```

When the client sends a request to `/summarize`, they'll receive a summary.zip file in response. The zip will contain two files: result.pdf (the processed PDF) and data.json (the JSON data).

On the client side (React), you'll need to handle the received zip, extract it, and process the PDF and JSON files as needed. There are various libraries available for handling zip files in JavaScript, such as [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).

**This should work for your intended purpose, but might not be the most user-friendly. You'll need to ensure the client app can handle and process the zip response appropriately.**

Comment: Thanks! although it looks a bit like a Chat-GPT response, I was thinking in *StreamingResponse* as a possible solution,sending a *.zip* file it's an interesting approach but I think @Krishnan Shankar *pdf_url* solution fits better

Comment: @Forshank I am just going off my personal experience with doing something like this, no problem! As long as you found a solution to your problem, that's all that matters